# Destroying a form with TIdHTTPServer causes Socket Error # 10038 Socket operation on non-socket

Tags: sockets, indy, delphi-6

Destroying a form with `TIdHTTPServer` causes

> EIdSocketError with message 'Socket Error # 10038 Socket operation on non-socket.'

if some HTTP request was already processed.

It makes absolutely no difference whether I create `TIdHTTPServer` with form as an owner and do not call `TIdHTTPServer.Free` in form destructor or set owner to `nil` and call `TIdHTTPServer.Free` in form destructor.

How to make `TIdHTTPServer` shut down gracefully without causing any debugger exceptions?

I found out only one way to eliminate this error:

```
destructor THFServer.Destroy();
begin
  _server.Active := False;
  Sleep(5000);
  inherited;
end;
```

but I think it's not the right way.

Comment: Unless the exception is actually crashing your code, I wouldn't worry about it.  I would expect something like that to sometimes occur within, and be handled within, the context of the server's own internal threads, not in the context of your main UI thread.

Comment: Remy Lebeau: It is harmless, but quite annoying.

Comment: Again, unless it is actually crashing your code (which I doubt), you should only be seeing it when running inside the debugger, in which case you can tell the debugger to ignore it.